# Anyway to populate a userform textbox with a public variable?

Tags: vba, variables, userform, public

I am trying to populate a textbox on a userform with a public variable to allow the user to copy and paste into an external program. I can pass basic strings into the textbox but cannot seem to pass a variable. Here is my current code:

**VBA Button-click**

```
Option Explicit
Public PathConfig As String
Public BuildableLand As String

Public Sub Import_Click()

PathConfig = "TestConfig"
BuildableLand = "TestBuildable"
CopyPaste.Show
CopyPaste.ConfigText.Text = PathConfig
CopyPaste.BuildableLandText.Text = BuildableLand

End Sub
```

**Userform**

Textboxes are named 'ConfigText' and 'BuildableLandText' respectively

[image]

**Userform Code**

```
Private Sub ExitForm_Click()

Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

CopyPaste.ConfigText.Text = PathConfig
CopyPaste.BuildableLandText.Text = BuildableLand

End Sub
```

When I step through the code it doesn't seem like the PathConfig/BuildableLand variables are holding their value over to the userform. Is Public variable not sufficient?

Comment: Try defining your `Public` variables in a `Module` instead of the form.

Comment: All of the other code in my excel file relies on buttons located within the individual sheets - so the variables I will be using/passing are embedded within the various sheets (i.e. objects). Can I pass from an object to the form without using modules?

Comment: Why would you not want to use a module? The forms will all be able to "see" them there if they are Public.

Comment: I have a lot of existing code written into objects including what defines the variables above and I would rather not copy all of them over to modules.

I presume just declaring the individual variables as public in a module will be insufficient to solve my issue. I just want something simple to copy a pair of variables from VBA into a web interface. Its a super minor convenience so if there isn't an easy way to pass a variable from the code that lives on a button in an object to a userform I'll just punt and move on.

Comment: To build on what @braX has said. Create a module and call it "MagicNumbers". Declare all of your public constants in this module. Also declare all your literal strings and numbers as public constants. Create a section in there (through using comment lines) for global variables. This will give you visibility of all  the "magic" that is intertwined in your code - then you can start fixing it.

Comment: But even with this _wrong code_ you could fix it. Just call `show` after the assignments. **But** you should really first learn more about [classes](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-class-modules/), [objetcs](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-objects/), [userforms](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-user-forms-1/) etc. And using an extra module for constants is a good idea but in this case not the way I'd recommend because your constants seem to be more like configuration values which I'd probably put in a hidden sheet or document properties.

Comment: PS Little addition for the fix: Remove the assignments in the `Initialize` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly improved version of the code above could look like that

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Import_Click()

    Dim frm As CopyPaste
    Set frm = New CopyPaste

    With frm
        .ConfigText.Text = PathConfig
        .BuildableLandText.Text = BuildableLand
        .Show
    End With

End Sub
```

Additionally create an extra sheet with the codename `shConf` for the configuration values you need and a module with the following functions

```
Option Explicit

Function PathConfig() As String        
    'Using Names instead of a direct cell reference would probably better
    PathConfig = shConf.Range("A1")
End Function

Function BuildableLand() As String
    BuildableLand = shConf.Range("A2")
End Function
```

There is no code in the userform initialize event needed.

You should also reconsider using `Unload` in the exit event of the userform as this destroys the class. Use `Hide` instead! With `Unload` the userform no longer exists and you cannot retrieve the user input.

Comment: Would there be anyway to assign variables to the PathConfig/BuildableLand rather than cell values?

The above code is a small section of a larger code where these variables are properly defined (as a full filepath) and I would like to then assign them. I could drop them to a cell as an intermediary step in the code I suppose but it seems clunky.

Could I do something really ugly like open the userform, copy variable to the clipboard, paste to the textbox, and repeat for the second variable?

Comment: I do not really understand what you need. This seems to be an XY-problem.